# Adjust code Retrieve the DOM from a given URL

Tags: php, html

Hello ,

im using the following code to  Retrieve the DOM from  URL
ind all "A" tags and print their HREFs
Now my output is contain "A" i dont want its my out is here 
http://trend.remal.com/parsing.php
some elements duplicated , 
i need to clear my out to be only  "A" that include  https://twitter.com/$namehere
as you can see i have 2 kind of urls i need only twitter url and  avoid duplicate
any tips to adjust the code

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

 $html = file_get_html('http://tweepar.com/sa/1/');
 foreach($html->find('a') as $e) 
 echo $e->href . '<br>';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$urls = array();

foreach ( $html->find('a') as $e )
{
    // If it's a twitter link
    if ( strpos($e->href, '://twitter.com/') !== false )
    {
        // and we don't have it in the array yet
        if ( ! in_array($e->href, $urls) )
        {
            // add it to our array
            $urls[] = $e->href;
        }
    }
}

echo implode('<br>', $urls);
```

Here are some references from the PHP docs:

- [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)
- [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)
- [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: perfect ,  works like i want ! one more adjustment , if i want to hide https://twitter.com/ and just parse the name after it like , https://twitter.com/test1 ,  and out put just print test1 ?!

Comment: @MarcoDonJuan - Make that a separate question.

Comment: done here is separate question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338381/adjust-php-code-retrieve-the-dom-from-a-given-url