# Adjust PHP code Retrieve the DOM from a given URL

Tags: php, html

Hello ,

im using the following code to  Retrieve the DOM from  URL
 all "A" tags and print their HREFs
Now my output is contain "A" i dont want its my out is here 
http://trend.remal.com/parsing.php

i need to clear my out to be only  the name after http://twitter.com/namehere

so output print list of "namehere"

```
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

 // Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
 $html = file_get_html('http://tweepar.com/sa/1/');
 $urls = array();

  foreach ( $html->find('a') as $e )
  {
  // If it's a twitter link
  if ( strpos($e->href, '://twitter.com/') !== false )
  {
    // and we don't have it in the array yet
    if ( ! in_array($urls, $e->href) )
    {
        // add it to our array
        $urls[] = $e->href;
    }
   }
   }

  echo implode('<br>', $urls);

echo $e->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: The parameters to [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) are backward. If you want to search _$urls_ for an instance of _$e->href_, use `in_array($e->href, $urls)`. That will fix the "Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given" problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of simply using `$urls[] = $e->href`, use [a regex to match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) the username:

```
preg_match('~twitter.com/(.+)~', $e->href, $matches);
$urls[] = $matches[1];
```